# How do I stop OS X attempting to import photos on each boot?

Tags: macos, iphone, photos

Everytime I boot my iMac up while my iPhone is attached it attempts to import photos, giving me a message as soon as I login about how it "can not import photos because the device is locked". This has started up in the last 3-4 days, presumably because of an OS X update (I'm on version 10.10.5).

I don't want it to try importing them on boot (and it's annoying getting this message on each boot), and I've already disabled various settings to stop it importing automatically when I connect my iPhone.

How can I prevent it from trying to import photos each time I boot my Mac up?

Comment: Is there any way to determine _which_ application is triggering the attempted import? Importing is disabled in both Image Capture and Photos.

Comment: I've tried disabling Image Capture via CHMOD 000, and that doesn't work either. I still get this pop-up every day.

Answer (score 2):

- Connect phone.
- Launch Image Capture [in Applications]
- Set "Connecting this iPhone opens:" - No application

[image]

Comment: Already configured like that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect the iPhone and select it in Photos.
2. Unselect Open Photos for this device

   [image]

Comment: Already unchecked. It is something else causing it I think. Would be easier if OS X told me what exactly was trying to import.